# App occasionally crashes when accessing google play services

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services, google-plus-one

In my app I'm using the PlusOneButton and I simulated an automatic click on the actual button - to save the user one more click.
For users that aren't signed in with their Google account the next screen that will be displayed is the builtin google dialog to choose an account.

Occasionally, the app crashes when it reaches this phase - I see the following lines in the log

```
1378-3640/? I/GLSUser﹕ [GLSUser] getTokenFromCache: [account: <ELLIDED:2885>, callingPkg: com.google.android.gms, service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pos]
1378-3640/? I/Auth.Core﹕ [TokenCache] Missing snowballing token: no granted scopes set.
1378-3640/? I/GLSUser﹕ [GLSUser] getTokenFromGoogle [account: <ELLIDED:2885>, callingPkg: com.google.android.gms, service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pos
6376-6376/com.myapp.android D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
6376-6376/com.myapp.android W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41fced40)
6376-6376/com.myapp.android I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 6376 SIG: 9
```

it seems that the crash happens after this line is written

```
[GLSUser] getTokenFromGoogle [account: <ELLIDED:2885>, callingPkg: com.google.android.gms, service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pos
```

because I don't see it in the log when there are no crashes.

**Right now it seems that disabling the automatic click solves the problem - any idea what can be done to enable this automatic click?**

Comment: How are you doing your "automatic click"? Is there nothing more in the logcat regarding the "crashes"? There must be a stacktrace..

Comment: There is no exception in the log - I'm doing the auto click by locating a child of the PlusOneButton and clicking on it

Comment: what you are doing is probably breaking the terms of service of the google api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is built of 2 parts

1. As noted by **TomTsagk** and **shkschneider** - there must have been an exception that was thrown, and there was! - the problem was that we used an experimental 3rd party sdk and it was swallowing our exceptions system wide
2. The actual problem that we had was that the plus one intent was null - it was a timing issue - so basically retrying the click until the intent isn't null solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your app throws an exception that is not caught, this means that some code connected with your PlusOneButton should be inside a "try/catch".

```
try
{
    /*Code regarding the button*/
} catch (Exception e)
{
    /*Code that executes if the code throws exception*/
}
```

Please post more code if that doesn't work so i can help more

Comment: It is exiting with Signal 9 - if you look here [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal) you can see that it cannot be caught or ignored. If there is an exception that wasn't caught in my code it would have been displayed somewhere in the general log

Comment: @NoaDrach are you sure? how about the line `6376-6376/com.myapp.android W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41fced40)
6376-6376/com.myapp.android I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 6376 SIG: 9` ?

Comment: my entire app is wrapped with try-catch using **crashlytics** no exception was caught

Comment: @NoaDrach then I'm not sure what the issue is, sorry